# React App needs Refreshing for updates

Tags: reactjs

I have created a React App and it works just has one thing bothering me. When I hit the add item to it, it takes me to the right page that lists the items added. But I have to refresh this new page to show the added item to the list. Also, in that list page, when I hit the delete button, a modal pops up, when I hit the delete button in the modal, it doesn't delete that item. I have to refresh the page and then the item is deleted! I was hoping that as soon as I hit delete, the modal goes way and item is deleted.
I have my code here:
IndexItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ItemService from './ItemService';
import axios from 'axios';
import TableRow from './TableRow';

        class IndexItem extends Component {

          constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {value: '', items: ''};
              this.addItemService = new ItemService();
            }
            componentWillMount(){
              axios.get('http://localhost:4200/items')
              .then(response => {
                this.setState({ items: response.data });
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              })
            }
            tabRow(){
              if(this.state.items instanceof Array){
                return this.state.items.map(function(object, i){
                    return <TableRow obj={object} key={i} />;
                })
              }
            }

            render() {
              return (
                <div className="container">
                    <table className="table table-striped">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Student ID</td>
                          <td>Student Name</td>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {this.tabRow()}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
              );
            }
          }

        export default IndexItem;

        class TableRow extends Component {

          constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.addItemService = new ItemService();
              this.state = {isOpen: false}; 
          }

          toggleModal = () => {
            this.setState({
              isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
            });
          }


          render() {
            return (
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    {this.props.obj._id}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {this.props.obj.item}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                  <Link to={"/edit/"+this.props.obj._id} className="btn btn-primary">Edit</Link>
                </td>
                  <td>
                  <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>
                    Delete
                  </button>
                    <ModalItem
                      show={this.state.isOpen}
                      obj={this.props.obj}
                      onClose={this.toggleModal}>
                    </ModalItem>

                  </td>
                </tr>
            );
          }
        }

        export default TableRow;

        import React from 'react';
        import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
        import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
        import {Modal, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

         import Item Service from './ItemService';
            class Modaltem extends React.Component {
              constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.addItemService = new ItemService();
                this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
              }

              handleSubmit(event) {  
                event.preventDefault();
                this.addItemService.deleteData(this.props.obj._id);
              }
              render() {
                // Render nothing if the "show" prop is false
                if (!this.props.show) {
                  return null;
                }
                else {
                  return (
                    <div className="static-modal">
                      <Modal.Dialog>
                        <Modal.Header>
                          <Modal.Title>Ready to Delete Student</Modal.Title>
                        </Modal.Header>

                        <Modal.Body>Are you sure you want to delete this Student?</Modal.Body>

                        <Modal.Footer>
                          <Button onClick={this.props.onClose}>Close</Button>
                          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <input type="submit" value="Delete" className="btn btn-danger" />
                          </form>

                        </Modal.Footer>
                      </Modal.Dialog>
                    </div>
                  );
                }
              }
            }
            }

            export default ModalItem;

        import App from './App';
        import AddItem from './components/AddItem';
        import IndexItem from './components/IndexItem';
        import EditItem from './components/EditItem';

        ReactDOM.render(
          <Router>
              <div>
                <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
                <Route path='/add-item' component={AddItem} />
                <Route path='/index' component={IndexItem} />
                <Route path='/edit/:id' component={EditItem} />
              </div>
          </Router>,
          document.getElementById('root')

    ItemService.js file

        import axios from 'axios';

        class ItemService {

          sendData(data) {
            axios.post('http://localhost:4200/items/add/post', {
              item: data
            })
            .then(res => this.setState({ items: res.data }))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
          }

          updateData(data, id){
            axios.post('http://localhost:4200/items/update/'+id, {
              item: data
            })
            .then(res => this.setState({ items: res.data }))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
          }

          deleteData(id){
            axios.get('http://localhost:4200/items/delete/'+id)
            .then().catch(err => console.log(err))
          }
        }

        export default ItemService;
```

Comment: please add the ItemService, show the code separate or using https://codesandbox.io

Comment: @zannu - Could you please share the code, so that readers get to know how the TableRow is getting props? Because the problem is only there, TableRow is receiving the updated props.

Comment: Hi @T.Judy, I added the itemservice.js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code that you have provided, the reason the content is not updating is because you are not calling **setState function with the changed list of items**. React does not re-render until the state changes for that component.

Comment: Hello @limbuster, where would I put the code for the setstate?

Comment: You have not shared all your code so I can't say exactly where but it should be in the component where you are listing your items so that should be where you are including **TableRow**.

Comment: What other code were you looking for? I also just pasted the itemservice.js file. Can you give example of what the setstate should look like?

Comment: I do not see the code where TableRow is being used because that looks like where the data is being displayed. So basically you need to add a new function there which calls setState(listofItems) and you should pass along the new function to any child components (e.g. the modal in your case) as props if any action in those component needs to update the data.

Comment: Hello @limbuster, I undersatnd what you are requesting now. I have placed my IndexItem.js code which calls the TableRow component. Can you please show me how I can setstate in this component? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I would change the **IndexItem** class and add a new function called something like **refreshItems()**. This will call the api to get the latest items (basically what you have in componentWillMount()) and from **componentWillMount()** just call **refreshItems()**. In the **tabRow()** method just pass along the **refreshItems** function. In tabRow and all the child components you will need to call this **refreshItems** as **props.refreshItems** whenever you need to refresh the list. Also, I see you have not bind you class functions. Good luck!